# NoMethodError (undefined method `permit' for "note_id":String):

Tags: api, python-3.x, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm having issues with an API in Rails4/mongoid application. I need to manipulate the data with a python 3 script through an API but I'm getting

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `permit' for "note_id":String):
```

error when I try to submit the request.

My python codes looks like this

```
import requests
import json
    url = 'http://0.0.0.0:3000/api/v1/note_proc_logs.json'    
    payload = {'note_proc_log' : { 'note_id' : '120904'}}
    head = {"Authorization":"Token token=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}
    r = requests.post(url, payload, headers=head)
```

The API controler

```
module Api
  module V1
    # This class does not inherit from ApplicationController like the rest to skip Devise authentication
    class NoteProcLogsController < ActionController::Base
      before_filter :restrict_access if Rails.env.development? == false

      respond_to :json

      def create
        Rails.logger.warn "note_proc_log_params: #{params}" if Rails.env.development?

        @note_proc_log = NoteProcLog.new(note_proc_log_params)

        respond_to do |format|
          if @note_proc_log.save
            format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @note_proc_log }
          else
            format.json { render json: @note_proc_log.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
          end
        end
      end

      private
        def restrict_access
          authenticate_or_request_with_http_token do |token, options|
            ApiKey.where(access_token: token).exists? 
          end
        end

        # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
        def note_proc_log_params
          params.require(:note_proc_log).permit(:note_id)
        end
    end
  end
end
```

I saw few question with the same error but couldn't find a solution to my problem.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE:**

`Rails.logger.warn "note_proc_log_params: #{params}" if Rails.env.development?`

gives me

`W, [2016-07-25T15:10:38.362848 #48352]  WARN -- : params: {"note_proc_log"=>"note_id", "format"=>"json", "controller"=>"api/v1/note_proc_logs", "action"=>"create"}`

Comment: You are in development right? Can you post the outcome of this line?
Rails.logger.warn "note_proc_log_params: #{params}" if Rails.env.development?
I would like to see the format of the params.

Comment: I think your payload is not generating proper Hash for params

Comment: Remove space from your payload keys and colon `:` in your `python code`  , here the new paylod `payload = {'note_proc_log': { 'note_id': '120904'}`

Comment: Thanks for helping out guys. @fabriciofreitag I updated the question. I guess you're all right, data format in payload is not right.

Comment: @HiteshSongra I tried your suggestion but it didn't work. I have another python script with the same formatting and it works, the only difference is that payload is a hash with key value pairs, all string, no sub hashes or arrays

Comment: As per your `Rails.logger.warn "note_proc_log_params: #{params}" if Rails.env.development?`, you received `{"note_proc_log"=>"note_id", "format"=>"json", "controller"=>"api/v1/note_proc_logs", "action"=>"create"}`, so here is the issue, it must be `note_proc_log[:note_id]` for `note_proc_log`. Format the passed `note_proc_log` params from your `python` code or re-structured in rails controller, it will fix your issue.

Comment: I had to change the format of `payload` in python code to something like `payload='note_proc_log[chip_id]=120904&note_proc_log[test_timestamp]=2016-07-19T13:24:49'`. Can't use symbols on the python side but can use them to reference once on Rails side in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the python script. A simple python dictionary is ok as payload but nested ones appear not to be.

My final python script look like this

```
import requests
import json

url = 'http://0.0.0.0:3000/api/v1/note_proc_logs.json'
payload='note_proc_log[chip_id]=120904&note_proc_log[test_timestamp]=2016-07-19T13:24:49'
head = {"Authorization":"Token token=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}
r = requests.post(url=url, data=payload, headers=head)
```

On Rails side everything will be treated as string so no need for adding additional quotation marks, even for strings with spaces, parent attribute has to be specified for each child attribute and elements separated with `&`.

This is what works for me, it would be interesting to know if there are other/better ways to do it, in particular how to include an Array of values.